# Selecting Random File in AppleScript

Tags: macos, finder, applescript

I’m trying to make a script that can select/display/open a file randomly from a folder and its subfolders. The following script:

```
tell application "Finder"
    get some file of (folder "/Volumes/Expansion Drive/Photos")
end tell
```

Gives following error:

**error "Finder got an error: Can’t get folder \"/Volumes/Expansion Drive/Photos\"." number -1728 from folder "/Volumes/Expansion Drive/Photos”**

What is the correct syntax? It’s a late 2013 iMac with OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: Note: The folder is on an NTFS volume on an external hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using the POSIX path syntax, you have to use `POSIX file` to get the object at that path:

```
tell application "Finder"
    get some file of (folder (POSIX file "/Volumes/Expansion Drive/Photos"))
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Finder to get lists of files [can be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2097263/348694) as well as long winded. I'd recommend to fall back to unix tools like this...

```
#
# Get list of files...
#   For example: all .txt files (not folders) under Downloads and below.
#
try
    set filelist to (do shell script "find ~/Downloads -type f -name '*.txt'")
on error eStr
    # Do something here...
    log eStr
end try

# Count the results
set n to count every paragraph in filelist

# Get a random no
set n to (get random number from 1 to n)

# Get the nth item from the results...
get paragraph n of filelist
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out a [short script](https://gist.github.com/oliveratgithub/b9030365c9ae483984ea) (from another party) to see how you can use to rename files in an ascending order.  This way you can get a sense of how indexes work.  I made the script below that works for me.  It sets the index of the files that are in the folder.  In the folder I have each file named from file1.. file2.. file3..

The script works as follows: sets the index based on the number of files, then chooses a random number between the lowest number to the index of files and then I use the GUI with "System Events" to tell terminal to open a file with the random number.

Note: I take advantage of a wonderful tool from Terminal that with tab you can finish writing to the end of the intended file so no need to type the rest.  [Howto link](http://www.macdaddynews.com/2014/07/12/enable-tab-completion-mac-os-x-terminal/)

```
set text item delimiters to "."
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Finder"
        set all_files to every item of alias "Macintosh:Users:Home:Documents:terminal:folder3notes" as list
        repeat with index from 1 to the count of all_files
        end repeat
        set randomnumber to (random number from 2 to index)
        say randomnumber
    end tell
    tell application "Terminal" to activate
    keystroke "open /Users/Home/documents/terminal/folder3notes/file"
    keystroke randomnumber
    key code 48
    delay 0.5
end tell
```

Comment: Why not just do it in a `do shell script`?